# AutoCompleteStringCollection - API - problem's

Tags: c#, api, autocomplete

I want to do AutoCompleteStringCollection in the text box (field) for records taken from an array (for user) - I'm using the API. My code looks like this:

```
var download_records = await api_serwer.LoadAllRecords(username);
            AutoCompleteStringCollection sourceName = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            foreach (var download_records_string in download_records)
            {
                string test1 = download_records_string.ToString();
                sourceName.Add(test1);
                textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = sourceName;
                textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
                textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            }
```

On the server side in the API, I have a regular SELECT that retrieves data from the appropriate table for the appropriate user.

Records are not added to the TextBox and are not displayed.

Maybe I should do it differently?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Records are not added to the TextBox and are not displayed.

Maybe I should do it differently?

Comment: Can you check if `LoadAllRecords` returns anything? I tried your code and it works for me.

Comment: Yes, if I add records to the ListBox () control, then I have all the records from the array, but they don't want to add to TextBox () and display to the user. Do I need to set field properties additionally?

Comment: Guy's. Any help?